# How can I create jpeg images(image per page) from a pdf using PDFSharp?

Tags: image, pdf, pdfsharp

I am currently using GhostScriptSharp to create jpeg images from pdf documents. And I am facing permission issues. So I wanted to move on to PDFSharp for creating images. I tried that as specified their wiki page, but that example is not complete, and when I was trying to save the stream as jpeg, it was not saving correctly.
Does anybody have a working example for the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample shows how to extract JPEG images that are embedded in a PDF file.

PDFsharp cannot render PDF pages, not to JPEG, not to any other format. You can find this in the FAQ list in the PDFsharp wiki.